# How do I download the deleted iOS simulator in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

So today I deleted all simulators. Now I want to download some of them again. But I can't. XCode shows downloaded checkmark in simulators that were deleted. When I click the checkmark nothing happens.

How do I download the simulators again?

[image]

Comment: try restarting the machine.

Comment: @Poles Didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you may have to reset xcode.

Comment: @Poles How do you do that? I uninstalled and installed xcode again and it still doesn't work.